# How to resolve Java Collections.sort() Comparison method violates its general contract Exception

Tags: java, spring, sorting, collections, comparator

I am using Collections.sort to sort a list in ascending order based on time field.
Below is the code

```
private String getShipmentInpickingTime(List<Shipments> shipments) {
        logger.info("in getShipmentInpickingTime");
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");

        Collections.sort(shipments, (o1, o2) -> {
            try {
                if ((!"null".equals(o1.getShipmentinpickingtime())
                        && !StringUtils.isEmpty(o1.getShipmentinpickingtime()))
                        && (!"null".equals(o2.getShipmentinpickingtime())
                                && !StringUtils.isEmpty(o2.getShipmentinpickingtime()))) {
                    return sdf.parse(o1.getShipmentinpickingtime()).compareTo(sdf.parse(o2.getShipmentinpickingtime()));
                }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            int count1 = 0;
            return count1;
        });
```

This method throws exception --

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract.
```

I went through the google regarding this issue- It says i am comparing bigger object to smaller object. I tried reversing the sequence of object, but no luck.

Comment: Can you please share fields and types of Shipments object?

Comment: Your shipments really have a timestamp that says "null" (not `null`)?

Comment: Your comparator _must_ comply to the requirements listed here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,T)

Comment: @GhostCat yes it contains null, but i have used check to prevent null values. what else can i do?

Comment: @JollyRoger The field is of type String i am converting it to date for sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You catch the exception only once if **either** of the elements fail to parse.

Consider three shipments with the following times:
A - 12:34
B - 34:56
C - null

With your comparator, `compare(A, C)` will return 0, `compare(B, C)` will return 0, but `compare(A, B)` will return a non-zero result, thus violating the general contract of transitivity.

One easy approach is to use the `Comparator.comparing` syntax to parse each element separately:

```
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");

shipments.sort(Comparator.comparing(
                   Shipments::getShipmentinpickingtime, 
                   Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparing(time -> {
                       try {
                           if (!"null".equals(time) && !StringUtils.isEmpty(time)) {
                               return sdf.parse(time);
                           }
                       } catch (ParseException ignoe) {
                           // Not a valid time
                       }
                       return null;
                   })))
              );
```

Comment: This gives me null pointer exception if time is null. I dont want to throw any exception, just want to sort the list in ASC order.

Comment: @ShreyaMahajan sorry about that. `nullsLast` always gets me tripped up. Please see my edited answer for the right way of using it.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention which line of code throws this error. I am not sure which StringUtils you used here, `com.sun.deploy.util.StringUtils` does not have `.isEmpty()` method. So I reimplemented it.

Here is a working code for your problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    getShipmentInpickingTime(new ArrayList<Shipments>(){{
        add(new Shipments("12:00"));
        add(new Shipments("12:03"));
        add(new Shipments("12:02"));
    }});
}

private static void getShipmentInpickingTime(List<Shipments> shipments) {
    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");

    System.out.println(shipments.toString());
    Collections.sort(shipments, (o1, o2) -> {
        try {
            if ((!"null".equals(o1.getShipmentPickingTime())
                    && !(o1.getShipmentPickingTime() == null || o1.getShipmentPickingTime().length() < 1))
                    && (!"null".equals(o2.getShipmentPickingTime())
                    && !(o2.getShipmentPickingTime() == null || o2.getShipmentPickingTime().length() < 1))) {
                return sdf.parse(o1.getShipmentPickingTime()).compareTo(sdf.parse(o2.getShipmentPickingTime()));
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    });

    System.out.println(shipments.toString());
}
```

Shipments class content:

```
public class Shipments {

    private String shipmentPickingTime;

    public Shipments(String shipmentPickingTime) {
        this.shipmentPickingTime = shipmentPickingTime;
    }

    public String getShipmentPickingTime() {
        return shipmentPickingTime;
    }

    public void setShipmentPickingTime(String shipmentPickingTime) {
        this.shipmentPickingTime = shipmentPickingTime;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Shipments{" +
                "shipmentPickingTime='" + shipmentPickingTime + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Output:

`[Shipments{shipmentPickingTime='12:00'}, Shipments{shipmentPickingTime='12:03'}, Shipments{shipmentPickingTime='12:02'}]
[Shipments{shipmentPickingTime='12:00'}, Shipments{shipmentPickingTime='12:02'}, Shipments{shipmentPickingTime='12:03'}]`